# Underscore between flag icons(links)

Tags: css

The problem I have is an underscore appearing between flag icons. Those icons are actually links so the user can change their language.

Here you can see what I mean: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Bca.png)

Code:

```
<div id="header">

<div id="languages">
    <a href="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>?lang=gb<?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) {echo '&id=' . $_GET['id'];}?>">
        <img <?php if ($lang['PAGE_TITLE_HOME'] != 'Home Page') echo 'id="flags"'; ?> src="images/languages/gb.png" />
    </a>

    <a href="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>?lang=ru<?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) {echo '&id=' . $_GET['id'];}?>">
        <img <?php if ($lang['PAGE_TITLE_HOME'] != 'Главная') echo 'id="flags"'; ?> src="images/languages/ru.png" />
    </a>

    <a href="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>?lang=gr<?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) {echo '&id=' . $_GET['id'];}?>">
        <img <?php if ($lang['PAGE_TITLE_HOME'] != 'Αρχική') echo 'id="flags"'; ?> src="images/languages/gr.png" />
    </a>

    <a href="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>?lang=sa<?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) {echo '&id=' . $_GET['id'];}?>">
        <img <?php if ($lang['PAGE_TITLE_HOME'] != 'الصفحة الرئيسية') echo 'id="flags"'; ?> src="images/languages/sa.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: provide code or jsfiddle

Comment: Done. I guess CSS ain't required.

Comment: This is a duplicate, sorry too lazy to track it down. The underscores are actually underlines on the links. To get rid of them, you could close up the spaces between the links.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Underscore between two image-links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003969/underscore-between-two-image-links)

Comment: CSS is the most important thing here actually. Just a guess but I'm guessing you need something like `#languages a { text-decoration: none; }`. More than likely you'll need to apply this to the hover event too, so the selector would be `#languages a:hover`

Comment: Thank you martincarlin87, it worked. I said it's not important to upload the CSS code since i didn't use anything special for the flags, just the opacity. Anyway, thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted in comments but will add an answer for completeness.

What you see isn't an underscore but actually the underline on text within the `a` tag (so there could be whitespace within it between the start and end of the `img` tag).

To remove it from the links:

```
#languages a { text-decoration: none; }
```

The reason for adding `#languages` in the selector and not just `a` is incase OP doesn't want to affect all anchor tags on the page.

To remove the `text-decoration` on hovering the selector would be:

```
#languages a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```

These can be merged into one CSS rule like so:

```
#languages a, #languages a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```